# Get Same Function used to load ajax content work on ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load all site via `ajax` for this I am using this, the code explains itself more than I can:

```
<script>
    function lage(url){
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('#plus').html(data);
    $('[href]').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var val = el.attr('href');
    var sal=  'lage(\'' + val + '\')';
    el.removeAttr('href')
       .attr('onclick', sal);
});
  });
}
</script>
<body  onload="lage('http://crossorigin.me/http://anycorssite')">
<div id="plus"></div>
```

The `lage()` function is not working on the ajax loaded content but is working on `onload` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably look for something like this:

```
<script>

    function lage(url){
      $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('#plus').html(data);
      });
    }

    var initialUrl = $('body').data('initialUrl');
    lage(initialUrl);

    $('body').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
      var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
      lage(url);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

</script>

<body data-initial-url="http://crossorigin.me/http://anycorssite">
<div id="plus"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `jQuery` to attach events. Instead using attribute `onclick` you can use `.click(..)` to bind the event to the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  lage('http://crossorigin.me/http://m.ndtv.com');

  $(document).on('click', 'a', function() { // dynamicaly bind event
    var el = $(this);
    var val = el.attr('href');
    lage('http://crossorigin.me/' + val); //< call lage function
    return false; // prevent to for default behavior (redirecting to href)
  });

  function lage(url) {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
      $('#plus').html(data);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.header {  background-color: red;  width: 700px;  height: 150px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header" />
<div id="plus"></div>
```

Comment: Nothing is happening on click

Comment: Still it outputs <a>content</a>

Comment: run it in jsfiddle, check yourself using any url like (wikipedia,news site's)

Comment: yupp they come with a href, but i want the href content to load using ajax in "plus" div

Comment: I already did that still it loads the url instead of ajax loading it, run the snippet yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work(I ranked that up), but first answer one works.